# Merging Two Dictionaries Values If They have The Same Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, letter

I am making a list word counter and trying to merge two dictionaries that have a counter for each character, but I keep getting the wrong outputs. Here is what I attempted in an effort to figure out why. Everything seems to go well except for the last two keys in the dictionary.

```
counts = {"a": 1, "p": 2, "l": 1, "e": 1}
new_counts = {"h": 1, "e": 1, "l": 2, "o": 1}

counts.update(new_counts)

for letters in counts:
    if letters in counts and new_counts:
        counts[letters] += 1
    else:
        counts[letters] = 1

print(counts)
```

What I need:

```
{"a": 1, "p": 2, "l": 3, "e": 2, "h": 1, "o": 1}
```

What I get:

```
{'a': 2, 'p': 3, 'l': 3, 'e': 2, 'h': 2, 'o': 2}
```

Comment: How about `letters in counts and letters in new_counts` instead of `letters in counts and new_counts`. You are not checking if `new_counts` is not `None` or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for-loop:

```
counts = {"a": 1, "p": 2, "l": 1, "e": 1}
new_counts = {"h": 1, "e": 1, "l": 2, "o": 1}

for k, v in new_counts.items():
    if k in counts:
        counts[k] += v
    else:
        counts[k] = v

print(counts)  # => {'a': 1, 'p': 2, 'l': 3, 'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'o': 1}
```

This is actually the fastest method. I tested it with `timeit` against [kosciej16's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332598/13376511) and his took 5.49 seconds, while mine took 0.73 seconds (for one million iterations). I also tested against [wim's dictionary comprehension answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332596/13376511) and that took 1.95 seconds, while mine took 0.85 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If we are in Python structures, actually it is a `Counter` that is ideal here.

```
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter({"a": 1, "p": 2, "l": 1, "e": 1})
c2 = Counter({"h": 1, "e": 1, "l": 2, "o": 1})
print(c1 + c2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an ideal place to use `collections.defaultdict`. Creating a new `defaultdict`, we iterate over both dictionaries' items and add their values to the `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> counts = {"a": 1, "p": 2, "l": 1, "e": 1}
>>> new_counts = {"h": 1, "e": 1, "l": 2, "o": 1}
>>> for k, v in counts.items():
...   d[k] += v
... 
>>> for k, v in new_counts.items():
...   d[k] += v
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'p': 2, 'l': 3, 'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'o': 1})
```